# How to cite a lecture note

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite a lecture note in my poster, that I found by google search.
What are the standard field I should include in bibtex?

The lecture note I am interested in is:
[this](http://neon.mems.cmu.edu/rollett/27302/302.L6.martensite.11Nov02.ppt)

Comment: See also [How to cite a University lecture (or its slides or script)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5635/35864)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your desired output will depend on the `\bibliographystyle{}` (.bst file) that you are using.  Nonetheless, you can always try an entry with `misc`.  E.g:

```
@misc{Cunha13,
  author        = {Jo{\~a}o Cunha},
  title         = {Lecture notes in Computer Assisted Diagnosis},
  month         = {February},
  year          = {2013},
  publisher={Faculdade de Engenharia da Universidade do Porto}
}
```

Comment: You can also add a link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35981/24956