# How could I cite from a video lecture/lecture note etc

Tags: citing

I found a question related to a lecture note here: [How to cite a lecture note](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183472/how-to-cite-a-lecture-note)

But how could I cite a video lecture (from Youtube, or from coursera, Udacity, etc.)

Thanks a lot.

**Update**

I would like to publish on ACM/IEEE conference proceedings. I want to create an item on BIB file to insert it in Latex document.

Comment: (1) Anyway you want; (2) according the rules set out in the style you wish to (or are required to) follow; (3) according to the bibliography style you are using (with BibTeX, that means the `.bst` you load, with `biblatex` according to the `style=<style>` option you load) -- many styles come with documentation.  We have no idea how you are constructing you bibliography, so we can't answer for (3); we don't know what style you like/need, so we can't answer (2); and (1) is up to you, though you probably want to include at least URL, date, title, author.

Comment: `biblatex`  defines the `@online` entry type and there is a `biblatex-ieee` package.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, then accept the provided answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When citing online sources, I was taught to cite at the very least the authors of the web page, the URL and the date the page was created. For a Youtube video, this might be the name of the channel and the date the video was posted.

An important addition to any web citation is the date you accessed it, as unlike print resources, webpages can change over time and the person reading your bibliography may not see the same information as you did at the time of citation.

For web resources, this is how I format my BibTex entries:

```
@misc{Stand, 
author = {O'Connor, J. J. and Robertson, E. F.},
title = {Emmy {Amalie} {Noether}},
howpublished = "\url{http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Biographies/Noether_Emmy.html}",
year = {2014}, 
note = "Accessed 11/02/16",
}
```

which looks like this

[image]

(blue hyperlink made using the hyperref package)

There are probably neater ways of doing it, but using the `@misc` means you can choose which fields you wish to enter. Your particular institution or assessor may demand additional information in your bibliography, so you can easily add those using this method.

Comment: Could you make an example on citing this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5SrAga1pno

Comment: I don't know the format or style of your bibliography. You can use the BibTeX example I have given in my answer to create your own entry. Stack Exchange is the kind of community that is willing to help you if you show some initiative at solving the problem yourself, by uploading a minimal working example. No one is going to do your work for you. My answer should be sufficient for you to cite the video yourself, as your problem does not seem to be with using LaTeX of BibTeX itself.

Comment: Well, I understood. Thanks @Natalie, I just would like to make a BIBtex entry for an Youtube video.