# what is the standard citation format (in biblatex) for a lecture given in a school

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

i want to cite a lecture given in a school. How is the standard way to do so in bibtex?

```
@unpublished{123,
author = {X. YY},
institution = {NASA aerospace school, USA},

year = {2014},
title = {Air pressure sensors}
}
```

Comment: See also [How to cite a University lecture (or its slides or script)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5635/35864), [How to cite a lecture note](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183472/35864). Note that with `biblatex` the type `unpublished` does not have an `institution` field. So the school needs to go somewehere else, maybe the `note` or `titleaddon` field. (I'm not quite sure if you use `biblatex` since you mention BibTeX so prominently in the title ...)

Comment: If the lecture notes are available online (that is publicly available via a URL), then you might as well use the `@online` type, where you can put the school into the `organization` field. Alternatively to `@unpublished` you could use `@misc` where the field `organization` is also supported.

Comment: `biblatex` or `bibtex`? You first say one, then the other.

Comment: Are there any news here? If not, I will vote to close a s a duplicate of [How to cite a University lecture (or its slides or script)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5635/35864) in due time.