# Biblatex - Conference course notes entry type?

Tags: biblatex

I would like to reference chapter 2 from course 36 course notes of SIGGRAPH 2002 (an annual conference in computer graphics), but I don't understand what biblatex entry type it should be.

The course notes have a clear publisher and editor, so it's not `@unpublished` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5635/how-to-cite-a-university-lecture-or-its-slides-or-script). It's not an article in the proceedings (or is it? I'm not sure if the courses are part of the proceedings) so it's not `@inproceedings`. It's not a book, et.c., et.c...

I'm hesitant to put it under `@misc` because conference course notes should be common enough to have a designated entry type.

Do conference course notes have a biblatex entry type? In that case, which one?

Comment: Well, if it is not in the proceedings, it should indeed not be an `@inproceedings`. Where did you get it from? Maybe `@online` is a good match, otherwise `@misc` will do fine.

Comment: @moewe The course notes can be found at https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~olano/s2002c36/ Look at Chapter 2. But honestly, I'm not sure of what constitutes the proceedings? Are the courses held at the proceedings `@inproceedings`?

Comment: Isn't this highly opinion based? I would use `@online` an link directly to the chapter file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This course (https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~olano/s2002c36/) does not seem to be contained in any official publication surrounding SIGGRAPH 2002. The only mention I could find was http://www.siggraph.org/s2002/conference/courses/crs36.html.

You could simply use `@online`. But `@misc` is also OK. I would even be fine with `@unpublished` since the whole thing does not seem to have been published in the way books are, much less like an `@article` with peer review and all.

`@inproceedings` (and `@proceedings`) entries are appropriate if the work/article appears in a collection the likes of [Proceedings of the 29th annual conference on Computer graphics and interactive techniques](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=566570&CFID=925525783&CFTOKEN=36702773#). The proceedings can be edited by the conference chair and published by or via the conference organisers (maybe by an associated publisher). Those entry types are essentially enhanced versions of `@incollection` (`@collection` respectively) with fields for more detailed information on the conference (venue, conference date as opposed to publishing/print date of the book, etc.).

Ultimately, it depends on the output you look for and on your style.

Comment: Fair enough. Now that I look again I can't find an editor or publisher. I guess I'll go with `@online`. Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!
I've had this issue countless of times, and I always come back to `inproceedings` when I need to use references from conferences, keynotes or workshops.

I usually do like the below (using nielsen as example):

```
@InProceedings{nielsen1994usabilityconference,
   author     = {Jakob Nielsen},
   title      = {Usability inspection methods},
   booktitle  = {Conference companion on Human factors in computing 
                 systems - {CHI} {\textquotesingle}94},
   year       = {1994},
   date       = {1994-04-24},
   eventtitle = {CHI {\textquotesingle}94 Conference Companion on Human
                 Factors in Computing Systems},
   series     = {CHI {\textquotesingle}94},
   publisher  = {{ACM} Press},
   location   = {Boston, Massachusetts, USA},
   isbn       = {0-89791-651-4},
   pages      = {413--414}, % noting the pages where i found it.
   doi        = {10.1145/259963.260531},
   url        = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/259963.260531},
   acmid      = {260531},
   address    = {New York, NY, USA},
   groups     = {Online Articles}, % personal organization
   numpages   = {2},
   urldate    = {1970-01-01},
        }
```

Another example:

```
@InProceedings{bhor2016analysisofweb,
   author    = {R. V. Bhor and H. K. Khanuja},
   title     = {Analysis of web application security mechanism and Attack
                Detection using Vulnerability injection technique},
   booktitle = {2016 International Conference on Computing Communication
                Control and automation (ICCUBEA)},
   year      = {2016},
   pages     = {1-6},
   doi       = {10.1109/ICCUBEA.2016.7860004},
   groups    = {Online Articles},
   keywords  = {Browsers;Computer crime;Databases;Monitoring;
                Payloads;Servers;Attack;Denial-of-service;SQL injection;
                Vulnerability;web application},
   urldate   = {1970-01-01},
}
```

Ultimately, it is very much up to you to decide, as long as you make sure that the information is correct.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. It was just to indicate. It is fixed now

Comment: Also note that in the case in question the lecture notes were not part of  'officially' published conference proceedings. In your case it is quite uncontroversial that one should use `@inproceedings`. But in the OP's case its more tricky.

Comment: In OP's case it is difficult to provide a _final_ answer, there is no definitive answer in my opinion. I just try to give some options :)

Comment: Indeed, I do believe however that in the OP's special case (I can't say anything about general things) quite a bit of evidence points towards it not being an `@inproceedings`. Most notably that the SIGGRAPH 2002 proceedings don't contain the course notes. In the examples you give, however, as I said, `@inproceedings` is just the right choice (even if things could be streamlined for `biblatex`).